# Right click, text capture

Tags: c#, user-interface, right-click

I have a c# application that runs in the bottom right corner of the page, i was wondering how i could go about making my application appear when the user selects some text anywhere (say a pdf, browser etc) and then right clicks, goes to my custome selection bit say and it pastes that text in to my running application.

If anyone made any sense of that could you advise me in to what i need to be researching to get it done.

Thanks

Comment: This is almost completely impossible.  Browsers and PDF renderers use custom selection implementations.  You can try accessibility APIs, though.

Comment: What do you mean by "runs in the bottom right corner of the page"?  If this is a web app, then is the page a part of your app?  Is this a back office helper running in a browser?  Is it some type of plug in that runs inside another (non-browser) program?

Comment: Or, are you saying you have a program which runs in the notification area of the desktop?

Comment: ys the programme runs in the notification area of the desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this dictionary which does something similar.

Here's its mode of operation (or at least what I think it does)
When there is a double click, it sends a key command (probably <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) to copy the selected text. It then reads the text from the clipboard.

For your purpose, you could implement the mouse listening and sending keystrokes with this article I found on CodeProject: [**InputManager library**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/InputManager.aspx).

You then retrieve the copied text from the clipboard and do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a [look at a Clipboard monitor](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the windows messaging api, probably there is a Text-selected event.